# Click event on bitmap giving exception

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, phonegap-plugins

```
 public class RateScreen extends MainScreen {
int mScrWidth = Display.getWidth();
 int mScrHeight = Display.getHeight();
 int mImgWidth = 40;
 int mImgHeight = 40;
 final BitmapField,bitmapField1,bitmapField2,bitmapField3,
      bitmapField4,bitmapField5,bitmapField6;
  final HorizontalFieldManager hfm ;
 FontFamily ff;{
 try{
  ff = FontFamily.forName("Times New Roman");}catch(Exception e){}}

// Use style bits from Font class, e.g. Font.BOLD
Font f = ff.getFont(Font.BOLD, 36);

 EncodedImage mImages[];
 Bitmap  mImgTable,mImgTable1,mImgTable2,mImgTable3,
      mImgTable4,mImgTable5,mImgTable6;

 LabelField labelfield1,labelfield2,labelfield3,labelfield4,l1,l2,l3;
 public RateScreen() {
  super();
  labelfield1 = new LabelField("",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
  add(labelfield1);
  labelfield2 = new LabelField("Rate This App",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
  labelfield2.setFont(f);
          add(labelfield2);
          labelfield3 = new LabelField("",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
          add(labelfield3);
          labelfield4 = new LabelField("Please choose one 
           of the options below",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
          add(labelfield4);
         l1 = new LabelField("",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
          add(l1);


          prepareImages();
          mImgTable=paintImages();
          mImgTable1=paintImages1();
          mImgTable2=paintChar1();
          mImgTable3=paintChar2();
          mImgTable4=paintChar3();
          mImgTable5=paintChar4();
          mImgTable6=paintChar5();


           hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
          final BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField
             (mImgTable , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE);
          bitmapField6 = new BitmapField(mImgTable1  , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE);
          bitmapField1 = new BitmapField(mImgTable , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE)
         {
              protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time )
              { try{
                  Dialog.alert("image changed");
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField1, bitmapField6);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField2, bitmapField);
                 hfm.replace(bitmapField3, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField4, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField5, bitmapField);
                  }catch(Exception e){ 
                      Dialog.alert("choose only one"+e);
                     }
                  return true;}};
          hfm.add(bitmapField1);
          bitmapField2 = new BitmapField(mImgTable , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE)
        {
              protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time )
              { try{
                  //Dialog.alert("image changed");
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField1, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField2, bitmapField6);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField3, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField4, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField5, bitmapField);
                 }catch(Exception e){ 
                 Dialog.alert("choose only one"+e);
              }
                  return true;
              }
          };
          hfm.add(bitmapField2);
         bitmapField3 = new BitmapField(mImgTable , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE){
         protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time )
              { try{
                  //Dialog.alert("image changed");

                  hfm.replace(bitmapField1, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField2, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField3, bitmapField6);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField4, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField5, bitmapField);
                   }catch(Exception e){ 
                  Dialog.alert("choose only one"+e);
              }
                  return true;
              }};
           bitmapField4 = new BitmapField(mImgTable , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE)
       {
              protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time )
              { try{
                 // Dialog.alert("image changed");
                         hfm.replace(bitmapField1, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField2, bitmapField);
                 hfm.replace(bitmapField3, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField4, bitmapField6);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField5, bitmapField);

              }catch(Exception e){ 
                  Dialog.alert("choose only one"+e);
              }
                  return true;
              }
          };
       bitmapField5 = new BitmapField(mImgTable , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE)
       {
              protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time )
              { try{
                 // Dialog.alert("image changed")
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField1, bitmapField1);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField2, bitmapField1);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField3, bitmapField1);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField4, bitmapField1);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField5, bitmapField6);
             }catch(Exception e){ 
                  Dialog.alert("choose only one"+e);
              }
                  return true;
              }
          };
          hfm.add(bitmapField3);hfm.add(bitmapField4);hfm.add(bitmapField5);
          add(hfm);
          l2 = new LabelField("",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
          add(l2);

          final HorizontalFieldManager hfm1 = new HorizontalFieldManager
          (Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.FIELD_VCENTER);

          BitmapField bitmapField7 = new BitmapField
         (mImgTable2 , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE);
          hfm1.add(bitmapField7);
          BitmapField bitmapField8 = new BitmapField
           (mImgTable3 , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE);
          hfm1.add(bitmapField8);
          BitmapField bitmapField9 = new BitmapField
         (mImgTable4 , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE);
          hfm1.add(bitmapField9);
          BitmapField bitmapField10 = new BitmapField
          (mImgTable5 , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE);
          hfm1.add(bitmapField10);
          BitmapField bitmapField11 = new BitmapField
          (mImgTable6 , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE);
          hfm1.add(bitmapField11);
         add(hfm1);

          l3 = new LabelField("",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
          add(l3);
          ButtonField btn=new ButtonField("Rate",Field.FIELD_HCENTER){
              protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
                {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyScreen());

                return true;
                } 
          };
          add(btn);


    }


 private void prepareImages() {
      mImages=new EncodedImage[3];

       EncodedImage image = EncodedImage
         .getEncodedImageResource("star.png");
       mImages[0] = sizeImage(image, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
       EncodedImage image1 = EncodedImage
         .getEncodedImageResource("star_blue.png");
       mImages[1] = sizeImage(image1, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
      }
 private Bitmap paintImages() {
      Bitmap result = new Bitmap(70, 50);
      Graphics graphics = new  Graphics(result);


       EncodedImage image = mImages[0];
        graphics.drawImage(15,5, mImgWidth, mImgHeight, image, 0,
          0, 0);

       return result;
     }
 private Bitmap paintImages1() {
      Bitmap result = new Bitmap(70, 50);
      Graphics graphics = new  Graphics(result);


       EncodedImage image = mImages[1];
        graphics.drawImage(15,5, mImgWidth, mImgHeight, image, 0,
          0, 0);

       return result;
     }

 private Bitmap paintChar1() {
      Bitmap result = new Bitmap(70, 60);
      Graphics graphics = new  Graphics(result);

      graphics.drawText("Very", 15, 0);
      graphics.drawText("bad", 18, 30);

      return result;
     }



 private Bitmap paintChar2() {
      Bitmap result = new Bitmap(70, 60);
      Graphics graphics = new  Graphics(result);


      graphics.drawText("Bad", 15, 0);

      return result;
     }

 private Bitmap paintChar3() {
      Bitmap result = new Bitmap(80, 60);
      Graphics graphics = new  Graphics(result);

      graphics.drawText("Average", 0, 0);

      return result;
     }

 private Bitmap paintChar4() {
      Bitmap result = new Bitmap(70, 60);
      Graphics graphics = new  Graphics(result);

      graphics.drawText("Good", 15, 0);


      return result;
     }

 private Bitmap paintChar5() {
      Bitmap result = new Bitmap(70, 60);
      Graphics graphics = new  Graphics(result);

      graphics.drawText("Very", 15, 0);
      graphics.drawText("good", 15, 30);

      return result;
     }

  public EncodedImage sizeImage(EncodedImage image, int width, 
      int height) {
      EncodedImage result = null;

      int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth());
      int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight());

      int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(width);
      int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(height);

      int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32,
        requiredWidthFixed32);
      int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32,
        requiredHeightFixed32);

      result = image.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);
      return result;
     }}
```

when i click on the bitmap first time the bitmap get changed but if i click other then it showing exception and bitmap not get changed.
i want to do when i click on any of the bitmap then it get changed by other bitmap.
how can i do this,if someone no help me.

Comment: exception :manager. replace :newField already has a manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont replace your `HorizontalFieldmanager` like that `hfm.replace(bitmapField1, bitmapField6);`. Just replce your image like that `bitmapField1.setBitmap(bitmapField6);` for All your images  ..

Its working in my case ..

Comment: welcome . if getting help from my ans than upvote and accept ans